# How to install cctrlapp on debian?

Tags: debian, software-installation, python, pip

I try to install the [cctrl command line client](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/quickstart) on a debian 8 machine.

Following the install instructions, I installed python, pip and then (via pip) cctrl

```
apt-get install python
apt-get install python-pip
pip install cctrl
```

Now `cctrlapp` and `cctrluser` exist as console commands. But when I try to run one of them, I get this error

```
ImportError: No module named Crypto.PublicKey
```

So I try to install that missing module

```
pip install pycrypto
```

but then I get another error (see the [`pip.log` file on this gist](https://gist.github.com/dialogik/3f9567351670b98fd1a3))

```
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-nQPN20/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-JYTF94-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-nQPN20/pycrypto
```

Who can help? What else is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue, install the python-dev package which include
the `Python.h` header file needed for compilation of pycrypto.:

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

But, you can also easily install the python-crypto package directly:

```
apt-get install python-crypto
```